# Uploading a file to S3 (frankfurt) gets an error authorization AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

Hi :) When I try to directly upload a file to AWS S3, I get this error:

`The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.`

Seems like I'm missing something with the signing of the v4 hmac authorization signature :\

The html file:

```
<form action="https://mybucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-upload" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="myPublicKey">
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="private">
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://localhost:8080/uploadAfter">
    <input type="hidden" name="Content-type" value=""> <!-- any file format -->
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256">

    <!-- The following are injected by Javascript -->
    <input type="hidden" name="key">
    <input type="hidden" name="policy">
    <input type="hidden" name="signature">
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-credential">
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-date">
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-signature">

    <input type="file" id="inputFile">
    <button id="form-upload-submit" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

The server-side Node file (the "getS3Credentials ajax request"):

```
var crypto = require("crypto"),

AWS_ACCESS_KEY = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
AWS_SECRET_KEY = process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,

dateNow = new Date().toISOString(),     
dateNowRaw = dateNow.substr(0, dateNow.indexOf("T")).replace(/-/g, ""),

expiration = new Date();
expiration.setHours(expiration.getHours() + 1);
expiration = expiration.toISOString();

var policy = {
    expiration: expiration,
    conditions: [
        {bucket: "mybucket"},
        ["starts-with", "$key", "files/filename"],
        {acl: "private"},
        {success_action_redirect: "http://localhost:8080/uploadAfter"},
        ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
        ["content-length-range", 0, 1024*1024*100],
        {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
        {"x-amz-credential": AWS_ACCESS_KEY + "/" + dateNowRaw + "/eu-central-1/s3/aws4_request"},
        {"x-amz-date": dateNow}
    ],        
},

policyString = JSON.stringify(policy),
encodedPolicyString = new Buffer(policyString, "utf-8").toString("base64"),

dateKey = app.crypto
    .createHmac("sha256", "AWS4" + AWS_SECRET_KEY)
    .update(dateNowRaw)
    .digest('binary'),

dateRegionKey = app.crypto
    .createHmac("sha256", dateKey)
    .update("eu-central-1")
    .digest('binary'),

dateRegionServiceKey = app.crypto
    .createHmac("sha256", dateRegionKey)
    .update("s3")
    .digest('binary'),

signinKey = app.crypto
    .createHmac("sha256", dateRegionServiceKey)
    .update("aws4_request")
    .digest('binary'),

signature = app.crypto
    .createHmac("sha256", signinKey)
    .update(encodedPolicyString)
    .digest('base64');

$.send({awskeyid: AWS_ACCESS_KEY, s3_policy: encodedPolicyString, s3_signature: signature, s3_key: "files/filename", s3_date_now: dateNow, s3_date_now_raw: dateNowRaw});
```

The client side js file:

```
document.getElementById("form-upload-submit").onclick = function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    formUpload();
};

function formUpload() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.open("POST", "/upload");
    xhr.responseType = "json";      
    xhr.onload = processUpload;     
    xhr.send();
}

function processUpload() {
    var response = this.response;

    document.querySelector("#form-upload input[type='hidden'][name='key']").value = response.s3_key;
    document.querySelector("#form-upload input[type='hidden'][name='policy']").value = response.s3_policy;
    document.querySelector("#form-upload input[type='hidden'][name='signature']").value = response.s3_signature;
    document.querySelector("#form-upload input[type='hidden'][name='x-amz-credential']").value = response.awskeyid + "/" + response.s3_date_now_raw + "/eu-central-1/s3/aws4_request";
    document.querySelector("#form-upload input[type='hidden'][name='x-amz-date']").value = response.s3_date_now;

    document.getElementById("form-upload").submit();
    //The error is shown here as xml page, after the submitting of the form with the redirect to the amazon upload url
}
```

Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: The signature you're adding to the form isn't correct - the v4 signature algorithm is a bit more complicated (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-authentication-HTTPPOST.html). There might be something in the sdk to help with that - I'm not familiar with the js sdk

Comment: So, according to the link you posted, I edited the OP, trying to sign correctly for v4 but I still get the same error :'(

Comment: You're not supposed to use base64 when creating the various keys - only for the actual signature.

Comment: Should I digest the various keys in binary encoding and the final signature in hex encoding? There are other things wrongs? Thank you for your patience..

Comment: The final signature is base64 - everything else binary

Comment: Done as you said. Same error, I really don't understand what is wrong o.O

Comment: Well you don't want x-amz-date (which should be now - s3 will reject requests if the gap between that and the current time) and the policy expiration date to be the same - the expiration must be in the future. There is an example at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html which you could use to check your calculations

Comment: Sadly nothing change

Comment: You should remove the AWSAccessKeyId field from the form, since AWS thinks it is the old signature and tries to unhash it with SHA1. you can also use SHA1 encoding but it's less secure. you can take a look at my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081794/browser-based-uploads-using-post) for the demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the field 'AWSAccessKeyId' from the form.
It appears that if you add this field to the form AWS tries to verify the signature with SHA1 and ignores the algorithm type you have mentioned.

Take a look at this [aws post example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html), and check that the fields in your form matches the aws form (you can use this [tool](http://www.diffnow.com/)

Another option is to use the SHA1 hashing